# Windows cmd versus bash for sys.argv - Python

Tags: python, cmd, argparse, git-bash

I was trying to run a python script in visual studio 2015 and I wanted to specify a path to my arparse function, however kept receiving an OSError. See Update the problem appears to be a difference in how argparse receives values from command instead of bash behaviour.

Whether I specify it like this

```
C:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Racing\XML\*xml
```

or like  this

```
C:\\Users\\Sayth\Documents\\Racing\\XML\\*xml
```

I get an OSError that the path is not found

```
OSError: Error reading file 'C:\\Users\\Sayth\\Documents\\Racing\\XML\\*xml': failed to load external entity "file:/C://Users//Sayth/Documents//Racing//XML//*xml"
```

**Update**
I copied the script and XML file to a test directory. From here I have run the script on 2 different shells on windows.

On command **cmd**

```
C:\Users\Sayth\Projects
λ python RaceHorse.py XML\*xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RaceHorse.py", line 42, in <module>
    tree = lxml.etree.parse(file)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:79720)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1782, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115914)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1808, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:116264)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1712, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:115152)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1115, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:109849)
  File "parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103323)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:104977)
  File "parser.pxi", line 611, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:103843)
OSError: Error reading file 'XML\*xml': failed to load external entity "XML/*xml"
```

When I change it to **git bash**
It reads the file I get an error however it shows its working.

```
Sayth@renshaw-laptop ~/Projects
λ python RaceHorse.py XML/*xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RaceHorse.py", line 50, in <module>
    nomination_table.append([race_id] + [nomination.attrib[name] for name in horseattrs])
  File "RaceHorse.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
    nomination_table.append([race_id] + [nomination.attrib[name] for name in horseattrs])
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2452, in lxml.etree._Attrib.__getitem__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:68544)
KeyError: 'race_id'
```

I have a simple argparse function

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=None) 


def GetArgs(parser): 
    """Parser function using argparse""" 
    # parser.add_argument('directory', help='directory use',
    #                     action='store', nargs='*')

    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+") 
    return parser.parse_args() 


fileList = GetArgs(parser)
```

**Update 2**
Based on comments am trying to implement glob to enable use of windows shells. 
glob is returning an error that its object the parser has no object len.

**updated glob parser**

```
def GetArgs(parser): 
    """Parser function using argparse""" 
    # parser.add_argument('directory', help='directory use',
    #                     action='store', nargs='*')

    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+") 
    files = glob.glob(parser.parse_args())
    return files


filelist = GetArgs(parser)
```

Returns this error.

```
TypeError was unhandled by user code
Message: object of type 'Namespace' has no len()
```

Comment: It looks like something is (trying) to change the path you specify into its [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) equivalent. Try using something like `\\C:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Racing\XML\*xml`.

Comment: Look at `sys.argv`; that's what `argparse` has to work with.

Comment: @martineau      that didn't work.  The system. argv works on bash not sure  what the difference is here

Comment: Glob (`*`) in `cmd.exe` is handled by command and not by shell (i.e. an application must know what to do when getting a glob). It is not a case with `bash`, which substitutes `XML\*xml` with all possible files separated by a space.

Comment: Ok cool so I will need to use a glob in argparse

Answer (score 1):

The following should work with both the Windows `cmd` shell and bash because it will glob any filenames it receives (which can happen if the shell didn't do it already):

```
import argparse
from glob import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=None)

def GetArgs(parser):
    """Parser function using argparse"""

    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+")
    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    files = [filename for filespec in namespace.files for filename in glob(filespec)]
    return files

filelist = GetArgs(parser)
```

However, I don't think having `GetArgs()` add arguments to the parser it was passed is a good design choice (because it could be an undesirable side-effect if the `parser` object is reused).

Answer (score 1):

even very short and simple I still consider it worth the answer not only comment because python is multi platform and for that reason when you work with path you should prefer using

```
from os import path
```

to avoid problems running your app on different platforms